# I don't know how to use the material ui swipeable drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I use material ui swipeable drawer that, when it is receiving data from the server, it displays something like loading.

[image]

After the data is received, the drawer should be opened to the middle of the page and the data should be displayed.

[image]

In this case, the user should not be able to close the drawer to the bottom, and can only pull it to the top of the screen and open it, and vice versa, close it to the middle of the screen.

[image]

**Now the problem is that:**

**1- Do not let the drawer close down**

**2- The possibility of swiping to the top of the screen and vice versa to the middle of the screen**

```
return (
<>
  <CssBaseline/>
  <Global
    styles={{
      '.MuiDrawer-root': {
        position: 'static !important',
      },
      '.MuiDrawer-root > .MuiPaper-root': {
        height: `calc(95% - ${drawerBleeding}px)`,
        overflow: 'visible',
      },
    }}
  />
  <SwipeableDrawer
    container={container}
    anchor="bottom"
    open={open}
    onClose={toggleDrawer(false)}
    onOpen={toggleDrawer(true)}
    swipeAreaWidth={drawerBleeding}
    disableBackdropTransition={true}
    disableDiscovery={true}
    hideBackdrop={true}
    disableSwipeToOpen={!searchCompleted}
    ModalProps={{
      keepMounted: true,
    }}
  >
    <StyledBox
      sx={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -drawerBleeding,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
        borderTopRightRadius: 8,
        visibility: 'visible',
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        height: `${drawerBleeding + 1}px`,
      }}
    >
      <Puller />
      {!searchCompleted
      && <>
        <Typography sx={[Styles.searchingText]}>
          <FormattedMessage id="searching" />
        </Typography>
        <Box sx={{ marginBottom: '15px' }}>
          <ProgressBar searchCompleted={() => {
            setSearchCompleted(true);
            setOpen(true);
          }}
          />
        </Box>
      </>}
      {searchCompleted
      && <Typography sx={Styles.searchingResult}>
        <FormattedMessage id="searchingResult" />
      </Typography>}

    </StyledBox>
    <StyledBox sx={{
      height: '100%',
      overflow: 'hidden',
    }}>
      {searchCompleted && results.length !== 0
      &&
      <VisualSearchResult id="visualSearchResult" />
      }
    </StyledBox>

  </SwipeableDrawer>
</>
);
```

---

**Edit:**

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-johnson-ur386n?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675)

I don't know why swipe doesn't work in the codesandbox. But what I want is that when the results are received and the drawer opens automatically, then the user can drag the drawer to the top of the page and open it so that he can see more results and vice versa swipe to the middle of the page and close it.

Comment: put it in codesandbox? not really sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I edited the question and added the  codesandbox link

Comment: It's working for me, is it not for u?

Comment: No , swipe not working for me

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Is the problem clear or should I explain more?

Comment: r u testing the swipe on mobile? because it works only in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no official way of making the drawer closed halfway. To achieve *part* of what you want, here is what you can do:

**Customize the drawer style, so it open fullscreen**

customize the component with `sx` prop, as the documentation suggest (https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/)

```
<SwipeableDrawer
        container={container}
        anchor="bottom"
        open={open}
        onClose={() => {
          toggleDrawer(false);
        }}
        onOpen={toggleDrawer(true)}
        swipeAreaWidth={drawerBleeding}
        disableSwipeToOpen={!searchCompleted}
        ModalProps={{
          keepMounted: true
        }}
        sx={{
          ".MuiDrawer-paper ": {
            height: "calc(100% - 64px)",
            top: 64
          }
        }}
      >
```

This way, the component will open fullscreen

Here is an edited version of the official documentation with drawer that open fullscreen: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-forest-wkjcyw?file=/demo.tsx